# Why TServerSocket Class not found at design-time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In `Comm_Ethernet.dfm` I declare a component of type `TServerSocket`:

```
object frmCommEthernet: TfrmCommEthernet
  object ServerSocket1: TServerSocket
    Active = False
    Port = 5555
    ServerType = stNonBlocking
    OnClientConnect = ServerSocket1ClientConnect
    OnClientDisconnect = ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect
    OnClientRead = ServerSocket1ClientRead
    OnClientError = ServerSocket1ClientError
    Left = 808
    Top = 8
  end
end
```

`TServerSocket` is declared in unit `System.Win.ScktComp` which is in the RTL, but it doesn't seem to be available at design-time because when I open my form it complains:

> TServerSocket class not found
>   [Ignore] [Cancel] [Ignore All]

However my project compiles and runs just fine (when this form is not open in the IDE). How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The components in `ScktComp` are deprecated and have been for a long time. You are expected to use different components, for instance Indy. One strong reason for the deprecation is that these components are not cross-platform.

You can still use the `ScktComp` components at designtime if you install the `dclsocketsNNN.bpl` package into the IDE.  Presumably Embarcadero doesn't install this package by default because it contains deprecated components.

Comment: By "they" and "them" do you mean `TServerSocket` objects? Or things of a wider encompassment?

Comment: The components in `ScktComp`

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, by default, the BPL package containing this unit is not installed in the IDE.

You must go:

> Components -> Install Packages -> Add

Then select `dclsockets160.bpl` in `Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin` (change according to your Delphi version)

How to find out in whic RTL BPL package a unit is contained is a mystery to me; it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: "*For whatever reason*" - because the components in that package were deprecated years ago.